# Can we track "tel:" and "mailto:" clicks from Email

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to track clicks in email if we have "tel:" and/or "mailto:" in HREF?

Currently I have those two HREF tags setup in email but it's not tracking number of clicks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bit unconventional, but yes you can track these.

You will need to use the [CONCAT()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm) and [REDIRECTTO()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm) functions in AMPScript to create the link and then convince SFMC that this is a trackable link.

CONCAT() will combine the tel: prefix with your phone number.

REDIRECTTO() is used to tell SFMC that this is a viable link to be including in the click tracking process.

Sample Code:

```
%%[
SET @Phone = '1234567890'

SET @callURL = CONCAT('tel:', @Phone)
]%%

<a href="%%=REDIRECTTO(@callURL)=%%">My link</a>
```

Please note though that the URL created by this process will not be visible in link tracking - it will only collect the amount of times this link has been clicked.

So for example, despite how many phone numbers you put in the above sample inside a single job (say by making @Phone pull from a data attribute instead of a constant), it will all be attributed to the 'link': `%%=REDIRECTTO(@callURL)=%%`

Comment: +1 you could also use a the alias tag

Comment: Adding Alias will count as a click in a report?

Comment: I tried @Gortonington method for Tel and mailto and it worked for both. 

Thank you.

Comment: @Data_Kid - Hmm...If you put in a variable as the alias, I suppose that COULD work for differentiation! If you have tried this and it worked, please let me know. Great thinking!

Comment: @Gortonington when you created this for a mailto did you experience issues in web clients i.e hotmail when testing?
I'm finding it opens to the URL and stays on the error page "Click the link below if the page does not load in 5 seconds"
it records the click but the mailto doesn't open

Comment: When a default mail client is not specified (on users machine) there are some email clients that will then cause the mailto link to either break or just not function. You will likely need to make some business rules around it and set conditional statements to display mailto link or link to a 'contact us' webpage, etc.

Comment: Has anyone any experience with this alias tag?