# How do you implement CONCAT() and REDIRECTTO() to track "tel:" clicks?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I am going off of the original question "Can we track "tel:" and "mailto:" clicks from Email? see link:[Can we track "tel:" and "mailto:" clicks from Email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199017/can-we-track-tel-and-mailto-clicks-from-email/269276?noredirect=1#comment406841_269276)

Can anyone comment on where they implemented Sample Code:

```
%%[
SET @Phone = '1234567890'

SET @callURL = CONCAT('tel:', @Phone)
]%%

<a href="%%=REDIRECTTO(@callURL)=%%">My link</a>
```

I've added `%%=REDIRECTTO(@callURL)=%%` into my Link URL but where to you add the `CONCAT()` in your email template?

```
%%[
SET @Phone = '1234567890'

SET @callURL = CONCAT('tel:', @Phone)
]%%
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a direct link to the question you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You place the CONCAT() function within the content block itself. I typically place it at the top. You'll see it in the email preview but it will suppress at send time and if you preview and test. Hope this helps.